# How do I get script that works on one sheet to work across copies of the sheet OR on instances of that spreadsheet created using the Template Library?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written a very simple script to get the active user's email and display it. The script is currently bound to one Sheets spreadsheet. I submitted this spreadsheet to my organization's template library, but when I create new spreadsheets from that template, the script does not function.

I'm wondering how to make the script function when copies of the spreadsheet it's bound to are made OR if people create new spreadsheets using the original as the template.

One option I've read about is to publish the script as a private Add-on. However, I don't have access to GCP, which I understand is needed to create an Add-on

```js
function onInstall(e){
  onEdit(e);
}
 
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var TIsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Technicians and Inspectors");

  // GET EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(email);

  //SET CELL A2 TO EMAIL ADDRESS OF ACTIVE USER
  TIsheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(email); 
}
```

Comment: Hello @SiddhantChawla, for your situation it seems that the best option is in fact to use an add-on. Why isn't this feasible? Moreover, what do you mean by "I don't have access to GCP"? Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 After doing some more reading and experimenting, I did figure out how to create an Add-on from my script. I created a "template" version of my spreadsheet and installed the Add-on to this spreadsheet and submitted it to my organization's Template Gallery. However now when I create new spreadsheets from this template, I don't think my onEdit() function is being triggered. I've read that this may have to do with authorization limitations, but I am not sure

Comment: Hello @SiddhantChawla, would you mind providing more information on that matter? You might want to take a loot at this link [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers). Cheers!

Comment: @ale13 Thank you for the link! I had read through this page, but I suppose I'm still confused about what to change. I've added my script to the original post

Comment: I know that when a user creates an instance of my spreadsheet from the template library, the add-on comes with that instance of the spreadsheet. However, I don't think my onEdit() function is triggering because the "activeUser" does not change to the User when he/she makes an edit...hope this clarifies a bit

Comment: Hello @SiddhantChawla, is the `onEdit` trigger installable? Moreover, you might want to check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle) as well as it explains more about `authorization lifecycle`. Did this solve your issue? Cheers!